# How can I check if a txt file only contains whitespaces

Tags: python, txt

```
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fname:
    data = fname.readlines()
    print(data)
    x = str(data)
    if x.isspace():
        print("only whitespaces")
    else:
        print("not only whitespaces")
```

I have tried this but it seems it doesnt work. I want to detect if a txt file only contains whitespaces and also `/n` if it is possible.

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean?

Comment: "I want to detect if a txt file only contains whitespaces and also /n if it is possible."
This doesnt work

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/161666

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `readlines()` returns a list with every single line.
What you want is the `read()` method, which returns a single string for the whole file. The code would look like this:

```py
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fname:
    data = fname.read()
    print(data)
    if data.isspace():
        print("only whitespaces")
    else:
        print("not only whitespaces")
```

Also, `isspace()` already considers `\n` and `\t` as whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` returns a list of strings. You need to check the element of `data`, not simply convert the list to str.

```py
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fname:
    data = fname.readlines()
    only_whitespace = all(line.isspace() for line in data)
    if only_whitespace:
        print("only whitespaces")
    else:
        print("not only whitespaces")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect all whitespace characters (space, newline, tab, vertical space, carriage return...), then `isspace` might work for you, just read the file as a single string:

```
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fname:
    data = fname.read()
    print(data)
    if data.isspace():
        print("only whitespaces")
    else:
        print("not only whitespaces")
```

If you really only want space and newline, you could use a `set` operation:

```
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fname:
    data = set(fname.read())
    print(data)
    if data.issubset({' ', '\n'}):
        print("only whitespaces")
    else:
        print("not only whitespaces")
```